# Im having running IDL code in Python, or just running the code

Tags: python, idl-programming-language

I am trying to run IDL I will attach it bellow code in python, I have tried idlmagic but nothing seems to work, is there maybe a different environment I should use?

```
import idlpy
wdir5='/C:/Users/Desktop/Task/Data/'#choose the right folder

uu=file_search(wdir5)

for i=0,n_elements(uu)-1 do begin

  wdir=strjoin([string(uu[i]),'/'])

restore,wdir+'Jz_2011-02-15T013412.sav'

nnn=size(jz)

file=file_search(strjoin([string(wdir),'*Bp*.fits']))
read_sdo,file,index_Bp,data_Bp,/uncomp_delete

nnn1=nnn[1]
nnn2=nnn[2]

help,nnn1,nnn2

;lie=nnn1/12
;hang=nnn2/8

lie=nnn1/4
hang=nnn2/4

;=============================================================
;jf=jz[0:lie,0:hang]nnn1/12
jf=jz[400:600,20:100]; choose the non-flaring region in the rectangular box
print,max(jf),min(jf)
a1=max(jf)
a2=min(jf)

;jf=jz[nnn1-lie:nnn1-1,0:hang-1]

jz_variance=stddev(abs(jf))
;save,filename=wdir+'jz_variance.sav',jz_variance

help,jz_variance

x=nnn1-lie
y=hang

;shu_xx=[x,x]
;shu_yy=[0,y]

;heng_xx=[0,x]
;heng_yy=[y,y]


;kj=jz[dims[0]-200:dims[0]-50,0:100]

;x1=dims[0]-200
;x2=dims[0]-50

;y1=0
;y2=100

column=2
row=1

pos=multi_pos(column,1,left_margin=0.04,right_margin=0.001,top_margin=0,bottom_margin=0,xmargin=0.042,ymargin=0)

!p.multi=[0,column,row]

set_plot, 'X'

;!p.position=pos[*,2,0]

!p.position=pos[*,0,0]
LOAD_VEL;,gamma=2
;PLOT_IMAGE,jz,xtitle='mA/m!U2',back=128,col=0,title='jz distribution';,charsize=2

;------------------------------------------------------------
jz_real=jz

jz_ploty=bytscl(jz_real)

ll=size(jz,/dim)

PLOT_IMAGE,jz_ploty,title=string(index_Bp.T_OBS),xtitle='jz (mA/m!U2!N)',back=128,col=0

;a1=min(jz_ploty)
;a2=max(jz_ploty)

;help,a1,a2
;print,min(jz_ploty)
;print,max(jz_ploty)

; Including color bar at the top of Jz_map
cgColorbar,Divisions=4,Minor=5,Format='(F0.2)',Range=[min(jz_ploty),max(jz_ploty)],position=[0.05,0.85,0.5,0.9],charsize=0.5

;------------------------------------------------------------------------
yy=findgen(y-1)
xx=replicate(x,n_elements(yy))
xyouts,xx,yy,'|',/data
;___________________________________________________________

;xx2=findgen(x-1)

xx2=nnn1-lie+findgen(lie-1)

yy2=replicate(y,n_elements(xx2))
xyouts,xx2,yy2,'-',/data

;-----------------------jz完成---------------------------
BINSIZE=2
!p.position=pos[*,1,0]
;print,jf
cgHistoplot,jf,/FILL, HISTDATA=h, LOCATIONS=loc, BINSIZE=binsize,charsize=0.8,ytitle='Number of pixels';,max_value=1000;,
binCenters = loc + (binsize / 2.0)
;cgHistoplot,imm_cea,/FILL, HISTDATA=h, LOCATIONS=loc, BINSIZE=binsize

;nnn1-lie:nnn1-1,0:hang

yg1=nnn1-1-(nnn1-lie)
yg2=hang

yfit = GaussFit(binCenters, h, Acoeff, NTERMS=3)

help,Acoeff

A2=Acoeff[2]
A1=Acoeff[1]
title='string(A2)'

jz_sigma=A2

;save,filename=wdir+'jz_sigma.sav',jz_sigma; SOHRANENIYE SIGMY

cgPlot, binCenters, yfit, COLOR='0', /OVERPLOT;,legends=string(A2);,title='string(A2)' FITTING LINE

xyouts,0.82,0.7,strcompress('!Ms!X'+'='+string(A2),/remove_all),/normal

x=A1
linecolors
vline,x,/data,color=9,linestyle=1
;hline,y,/data,color=8

vline,x+A2,/data,color=2,linestyle=1
vline,x-A2,/data,color=2,linestyle=1

endfor

end
```

Is there a conversion chart I can use, maybe to try to rewrite the code or run in in a different way? One of the problems is also I do not know what the code does since I can not run, therefore I cannot rewrite it in Python

Answer (score 0):

I would look up the IDL routines in the [documentation](https://www.l3harrisgeospatial.com/docs/funclisting.html) to determine what the IDL code is doing. Then figure out how to do that in Python. There are [several](http://fiss.snu.ac.kr/fisspy/cheat/) [cheatsheets](http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/idl-python-xref.pdf) that give basic conversions between IDL and Python.